# Clojure: Idiomatic way to make in-place changes to a large data structure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Assume that you have loaded a large data structure (like a table index in a database) and now you want to make a change.

If I understand correctly, you need to create a new state (including you change) based on the current state (what you have loaded from the disk) and assign it to the current identity that you have.

This will be pretty slow in a large data structure because runtime needs to duplicate a big chunk of memory. Is there a practical alternative?

Comment: It's not slow because the new and old structures share data. Not everything is copied. Just use `update` or `assoc `. You can use transients to make it faster though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate What if they cannot share? For example for an array which AFAIK is a sequence of consecutive memory bytes, change in one byte will result in a new state.

Comment: Do you mean a Java array, or a Clojure vector? There's a difference.

Comment: If you're using Clojure, you should really use Clojure data structures whenever possible.

Comment: This question is unclear - the way to make changes to a data structure depends on the structure itself. If it is mutable then you can simply mutate it, if it is immutable then you have to create new values. If you have a sequence of changes to apply then you can use [`transients`](https://clojure.org/reference/transients).

Comment: Java arrays? For Clojure vectors, it seems they support cheap mutation.

Comment: @mahdix Yes, vectors are cheap to modify. If you're asking about Java arrays, it's really the same answer as if you were asking from a Java perspective. You'd use Java's array methods/subscripting to modify it, and I'd expect it would be as efficient as if you were doing it in Java. The performance of modifying an array shouldn't depend on the size of the array though (unless you're "appending" and need to copy it). Overwriting a cell is O(1) afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a practical alternative?

If the choice of database is within your control, you could take a look at [Datomic](http://www.datomic.com/index.html), which is designed to work with the grain of Clojure. As I understand it (not much, to be honest)

- differential updates to data you subscribe to are forwarded to you; and
- the data is maintained immutably and persistently on the client side
  too: if you keep a handle on what it was, that never changes, even if
  what it is (with a different handle) is different.

To get these characteristics, you use [the peer library, not the client library](http://docs.datomic.com/clients-and-peers.html).

---

If I'm talking nonsense, knowledgeable reader, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of good overviews of Clojure's immutable data structures:

- https://youtu.be/dzP05hEDNvs
- https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey

As the comments say, they don't copy the whole data structure when you make a small change. Instead, the "old" and "new" versions share data for the parts that didn't change, making the "persistent" data structures quite efficient.